# Date issues SQL first day of month crossover

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Here is my issue week of year 27 shows 2 dates as the crossover for the month happens it generates another 1st day of month date, 
i only want to show to first date in every instance that this happens

```
Datetime----------------|WeekofYear ------|FirstDayOfMonth
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 |27 --------------|2015-06-01 00:00:00.000
2015-07-01 00:00:00.000 |27 --------------|2015-07-01 00:00:00.000
```

```
CREATE TABLE #weekonweek
(
[Datetime] datetime,
[WeekofYear] int,
[FirstDayOfMonth] datetime
)

INSERT INTO #weekonweek

SELECT 
min(c.Datetime),
c.WeekOfYear
,c.FirstDayOfMonth

FROM Calendar c
WHERE YEAR = 2015
and WeekOfYear = 27
GROUP BY WeekOfYear ,c.FirstDayOfMonth
SELECT * FROM #weekonweek


CREATE TABLE #subtable
(
[Datetime] datetime,
[WeekofYear] int,
[FirstDayOfMonth] datetime,
)

INSERT INTO #subtable

SELECT 
c.Datetime,
w.WeekOfYear,
min(w.FirstdayofMonth)
FROM Calendar c
LEFT JOIN #weekonweek w on c.WeekOfYear  = w.WeekofYear
WHERE YEAR = 2015
and c.WeekOfYear = 27
and w.FirstDayOfMonth <w.FirstDayOfMonth
group by c.Datetime,
w.WeekOfYear
SELECT * FROM #subtable
DROP TABLE #subtable
DROP TABLE #weekonweek
```

Comment: pls add Structure for Calendar table..

Comment: @AbhayChauhan im 700 characters too much with the structure

Comment: To be clear, provide desired output.

Comment: Datetime Date ShortDate FullDate DayOfMonth DaySuffix DayName DayOfWeek DayOfWeekInMonth DayOfWeekInYear DayOfQuarter DayOfYear WeekOfYear Month MonthName MonthOfQuarter Quarter QuarterName Year YearWeek MonthYear Period FirstDayOfWeek LastDayOfWeek FirstDayOfLastWeek LastDayOfLastWeek FirstDayOfMonth LastDayOfMonth FirstDayOfLastMonth LastDayOfLastMonth FirstDayOfQuarter LastDayOfQuarter FirstDayOfYear LastDayOfYear IsWeekday IsEnglishHoliday EnglishHoliday WeeklyPeriod

Comment: Datetime----------------|WeekofYear ------|FirstDayOfMonth
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 |27 --------------|2015-06-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: @stanislovasKalasnikovas ^^ the first date in the example at the top

Comment: but not specifically for this week of year and or those dates, i can happen anywhere where there is a week of year number, but two first of the month dates

Comment: do you want the first day of the first week for the chosen month ? (comments to improve the question should be included in the question). Could you add some input and expected results please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DR.DivNo
    ,p.[ProductCode]
    ,p.ProductClass
    ,p.EmpNo
    ,[Description]
    ,[CGNo]
    ,[SCGNo]
    ,dr.Retail
    ,bd.[Buying Director]
INTO #Product
FROM [PRODUCT] p
LEFT JOIN [DIVRETAIL] DR ON p.ProductCode = DR.ProductCode
WHERE dr.ValidTo IS NULL
    AND dr.DivNo NOT LIKE '8__'
GROUP BY DR.DivNo
    ,p.[ProductCode]
    ,p.ProductClass
    ,p.EmpNo
    ,bd.[Buying Director]
    ,[Description]
    ,[CGNo]
    ,[SCGNo]
    ,dr.Retail



SELECT TOP 1000 [Datetime]
        ,[FirstDayOfWeek]
        ,[FirstDayOfMonth]
        ,s.NoOfStores
        ,s.DivNo
    INTO #stores
    FROM [Calendar] c
    LEFT JOIN Stores s ON c.FirstDayOfMonth = s.Validfrom
    WHERE DATETIME = firstdayofweek
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you wanna to achieve this ouput:

```
Datetime----------------|WeekofYear------|FirstDayOfMonth 
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 |27--------------|2015-06-01 00:00:00.000
```

You simple need to use `TOP 1` and add `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * -- like this
FROM #subtable
ORDER BY DateTime -- here you need to pass ORDER BY
```